# SSH: "Permissions 0644 for 'my_key.pub' are too open."

Tags: ssh, permissions, file-permissions, ssh-keys

Why is `0644` i.e. `-rw-r--r--` too open for a SSH key? Also I could not find any false permissions on the `.ssh` directory (`0700`) or the home directory (`0731`).

Btw I'm getting this error when testing the paraphrase of a key via `ssh-keygen -y -f my_key.pub`

Best regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may be running ssh-keygen on the wrong file. `ssh-keygen -y` operates on a *private* key file. ".pub" files normally contain the *public* key. You probably have a file there named `my_key`, without any extension, and it ought to be mode 0600. That is the file which should contain the private key.

To directly answer your question, SSH keys are normally used to permit connecting to remote servers without a password. Possession of the private key would permit someone to log into your account on any system which accepts the key. ssh-keygen and the other ssh utilities require private key files to have restricted permissions because the files are sensitive and need to remain secure.

Answer (score 36):

The only command you need to run is `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.  That's it.

This changes the permissions on the file so that the owner (you) can read and write it, which will remove the error message you receive.

Answer (score 13):

`0644` in not supposed to be too open for a public key, but is too open for your private key.

Your private key should have permission `0600` while your public key have permission `0644`.

By the way, you should also take care of the permission on `.ssh` folder. It should has the permission `0700`, so that only you, the owner, has control over the folder.

As to your home directory, write permission is not supposed to be granted to group and others.

Run `chmod go-w /home/username` should fix that.

Comment: Absolutely do not follow these instructions.  This is NOT what you should do.  This will also reset all home directory permissions.  You should ONLY be modifying the `.ssh` folder and the `id_rsa` file itself, not your entire home directory!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [Github instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) and erroneously put the public key as "IdentityFile". Specifying the correct key file fixed this issue for me:

```zsh
Host *
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
 - IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
 + IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers above are valid but before running any `chmod` to fix permissions, just make sure your `IdentityFile`(s) in `~/.ssh/config` do refer to your private key. Novices could misundertand that and refer to the public key (with `.pub` extension) instead, thus leading to that same error (since the public key file permissions are too open for a private key).